# More than one comma restrict using javascript

Tags: javascript

In my textbox I allowed only integer value and comma it will control using javascript.Now my doubt how to control more than comma continuously (i.e)**1,2,3,4** is to ok then **1,2,3,,4,,5** its need restricted.Its possible in javascript.

```
<p:inputText onKeyPress="onlyAllowDigitComma(event);"/>
```

Comment: can you provide onlyAllowDigitComma function  code????

Comment: We understand that everyone is not a native English speaker, but standard international English does not use "doubt" in this sense, we use "question". Also, it places spaces after full stops, and uses apostrophes in words like "it's" (when an abbreviation of "it is"). The correct capitalization for the language is "JavaScript".

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to validate your input. If the first match you get is the same as the whole input, then you're good to go.

The regex you're looking for is `/(\d,?)*/g` ([Test Link](https://regex101.com/r/tL7qO5/2))

For the sake of simplicity, I did the following code with the 'keyup' event to avoid shortcuts problems. You may also want to check on copy / paste event.

```
let myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
let myInputValue = myInput.value;

myInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    if(isPerfectMatch(myInput.value, /(\d,?)*/g)){
    console.log('Format is correct.');
    myInputValue = myInput.value;
  }
  else {
    console.log('Wrong format');
    myInput.value = myInputValue;
  }
});

function isPerfectMatch(value, regex){
  let match = value.match(regex);
  return match !== null && match[0] == value;
}
```

([Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6agzcx9w/))

Answer (score 0):

Your answer doesn't show how far you go with your solution. I suppose code bellow is what you wanted, also I suppose you need removing comas from start and end.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="onlyAllowDigitComma(event,this);" onkeyup="onlyAllowDigitComma(event,this);"/>
<script>
function  onlyAllowDigitComma(e,l){
    var k = e.which;
    if ((k <= 47 || k >= 58 ) && k!=44 && k!=8 && k!=0) {
        e.preventDefault()
    };
    l.value=l.value.replace(/,,/g,',');
}
</script>
```